# Looping only with last value

Tags: arrays, matlab, loops

I'd like the code to loop for every value in the array but it seems it only loops for the last value
here is the code

```
marks_list=[20, 50, 80];
for i = 1:length(marks_list)
if marks_list<39
    disp("Fail");
elseif marks_list <69
    disp("Pass");
else 
    disp ("Distinction");
end
end
```

What is wrong?

Comment: This is matlab by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to index `marks_list` with `i`:

```
marks_list=[20, 50, 80];

for i = 1:length(marks_list)
  if marks_list(i) < 39
    disp("Fail");
  elseif marks_list(i) < 69
    disp("Pass");
  else 
    disp ("Distinction");
  end
end
```